# Laptop connected to monitor freezes

Tags: windows-7, laptop, multiple-monitors, freeze, hdmi

Here's what happens:

I work on my laptop (Dell Inspiron n5110), which is connected to a monitor via HDMI.

Out of the sudden it freezes completely, the mouse won't move, the music stops, *everything is at halt*. Then I unplug the HDMI cable, wait for about 15 seconds and the laptop switches back to it's primary screen and everything continues (the music and etc) as normal. Then I plug back the HDMI cable and continue as usual.

I switched to a VGA cable, and the same happens as well. Also it happens on different monitors.

Why does this happen? Is it a symptom of some issue?

Comment: Are you sure it's related to the fact that you have additional monitor plugged in? Does it happen when working only with the laptop's display?

Comment: I have a monitor attached quite often, so in all cases it happened when it was plugged in.

Comment: I have the same problem with a Dell Inspiron laptop. It's driving me nuts. I have to plug and unplug the monitor a dozen times and then it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On board video drivers have been quite evil to me in the past, and can certainly bring your entire system to a halt. If this is happening with multiple monitors/cables, the next source to test is your on board graphics - of course assuming you haven't installed any additional GPUs. Make sure you have the most up to date drivers.

Comment: I'll definitely try this and report if it fixes the problem.